# Jenkins Cannot run program "python" CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, jenkins

When I run below python script using Jenkins, it is throwing below error.

```
Jenkins Cannot run program "python" CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Below is my code and it works when I execute it directly.

```
import _mssql,os,datetime
if (os.getenv('ColumnName').isspace() or not os.getenv('ColumnName')):
    print("White space Entered")
else:
    print(var)
```

I am running Python 3.5.

Thank you.

Tried python -v and getting same error

```
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "D:\test\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:108)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:65)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1729)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Build step 'Execute Python script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: In your jenkins job, instead of executing above script execute this command - "python -V". If this executes successfully, then execute this script as - python <complete path of script>"

Comment: your code is irrelevant. the python executable cannot be found because it's not in the PATH. Try to echo the path from jenkins.

Comment: Getting same error.

Comment: On which machine jenkin job is executing ? Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am running on windows machine and confirmed the path is added in env variables.

Comment: Try like - C:\Python35\python.exe <complete path of script>

Comment: It might be in your path on the pc but is Jenkins and Python picking up your path?  I've seen simillar before - and it required the env to be configured in Jenkins.

Comment: @DineshPundkar was it solved?

Answer (score 0):

Above error has nothing to do with you python code.

Add below to your Jenkins Job:

```
set PATH=<Python Installation Path>;%PATH%
python <Complete path to your script>
```

Comment: The issue is not with my script or env variables. I think the Jenkins plugin is having issues with Python 3.5 version. I tried running the same command as windows batch file from Jenkins and it worked. (python d:\test.py)

Comment: i want to write scripts under my Jenkins console and run them, any idea how to do that.